# Send PHP Array data to html table

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm not a PHP pro and would really appreaciate some help with displaying some array data (pulled from an XML file) in an HTML table format.

My array is setup as follows:

```
$strTodayIs = date('l F/n');
    foreach($xml->last7days->day AS $Daily) {
        //if (date('l F/n',(int)$Daily->starttime) != $strTodayIs) {
            $intAverageLastweek += (int)$Daily->avgresponse;
            $intDowntimeLast7 += (int)$Daily->totaldowntime;
            $intUptimeLast7 += (int)$Daily->totaluptime;
            array_push($arrLastWeek, array( "starttime" => $Daily->starttime,
                                            "response" => $Daily->avgresponse,
                                            "totalup" => $Daily->totaluptime,
                                            "totaldown" => $Daily->totaldowntime
                                           ));
        //}
    }
```

I'm trying to display the results of some simple percentage calculations in an HTML table, using the data from the `$arrLastWeek` array.

My end goal is to display the background colour of each cell depending on the calculated value of the data from the array, e.g. 100 = green, 100 to 99.8 = yellow, less than 99.8 =red.

Again, any help even pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if I've left out any important info that could help me solve my problem?

Regards,

Eli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're going to do something like this:

```
<?php foreach($array as $line): ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $line['value']; ?></td><td><?php echo $line['value2']; ?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can do math by setting PHP variables to zero before the foreach, and adding to them inside the foreach, and outputting them somewhere.

Good luck

Comment: Many thanks for the above. Greatly appreciated. I will try and implement this later today, and let you know how I go.